# Replace input value on typing in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `input` with `maxLength` of `1`. I want that if I type another `value` (**key**) the **current** `value` (**letter**) that inside the input will be replaced with the new `value` (**letter** of **key**).

I've tried something like that:

```
container.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
    var letter = target.value;
    var newLetter = letter.replace(/letter/g, letter);
    letter.value = newLetter;
});
```

Comment: but if you limit the maxlength to 1 how will you be able to type another letter?

Comment: @RamRaider as I said, I don't want another letter, I want the letter to be replace on each time I type in new value..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can update the value of the input box using `this.value` and get the key pressed using `e.key`. This will, however, enter meta keys if pressed:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  this.value = e.key;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="container" maxlength="1" />
```

The issue with the meta keys could be fixed by checking whether or not `e.key` is an alphabetic/digit letter by using a regular expression:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
container.addEventListener('keyup', function({key}) {
  if(/^[a-z0-9]$/i.test(key)) {
    this.value = key;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="container" maxlength="1" />
```

Comment: please add some form of a validation in case of special keys, for instance if i were to press Enter the input field value will be a string "Enter" which is probably not what the author intended

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski Hi, thanks for the tip. I've added some validation (in the second code snippet)

Comment: `event.keyCode` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Comment: @KooiInc oh, you're right, what would be a better alternative to get the key code? (`.code` will give a string)

Comment: I have a function that check for validation of only characters, will it do the trick ?

Comment: @user12499410 yes, if your function returns true/false you can use it like so `if(yourFunction(key)) {this.value=key;}`. I've changed my answer to not use keycode and to do the check by using a regular expression

Comment: @NickParsons The `{key}`-check is fine, the `RegExp` can be simplified to `/^[a-z0-9]$/i`. Up for discussion is if you want to use `this` or `event.target`

Comment: @KooiInc Ah, thanks for the regex simplification, that is much cleaner. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 1):

This works for all single character inputs while excluding the space character:

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  let valueLength = this.value.length;

  if(this.value == " ") {
      this.value = "";
      return;
  }
  
  if(valueLength == 1) {
    if( !e.altKey && !e.ctrlKey && !e.shiftKey && !e.metaKey 
        && e.code != "Space" && e.key.length == 1) {
      this.value = e.key;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="container" type="text" value="" maxLength="1" />
```